# Which thread will call GLFW callbacks?

Tags: glfw

I find these functions can register a callback for event from hardware(maybe? I'm not sure).

Like following functions.

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);
```

I'm curious that how are these functions called. Does GLFW create a new thread by `glfwInit` to loop these functions? Or does GLFW register some listeners to listen these event from different hardware?

Answer (score 1):

I track the running program and find that the function is called in the main thread. And I find that the function is called in glfwPollEvents. And it means that the hardware input is saved in the buffer and opengl will get the input and do the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the GLFW API is specified to only be used on the main thread (the thread that your application starts on). Every callback will be executed on this thread, within a call to `glfwPollEvents` or `glfwWaitEvents`. Your callbacks will never be executed on any other thread.